# JBoss - War library dependencies

Tags: java, jboss

I am trying to add some dependencies jar files. But these files when put in `lib/endorsed` or in `WEB_INF/lib.jar` results in startup error for jboss instances. I suppose this is happening because flat classloader structure of JBoss. If somebody has implemented the classloader settings in `jboss-web.xml`

```
<class-loading> 
      <loader-repository>com.example:archive=unique-archive-name</loader-repository> 
</class-loading>
```

Can somebody give me a real life example ?

Also where should I place these jar files - `lib/endorsed` of jboss, or `lib` folder in deploy folder or in `WEB_INF/lib`

Answer (score 5):

Duffymo's directive on not putting jars in ***endorsed*** is ignored at your peril.

In some additional detail:

Placing libraries in your **WEB-INF/lib** is a best practice for portability and consistency as it adheres to a standard provision for creating self-sufficient and distributable web archives, but you need to pay close attention to the **class-loading** declaration you're putting in your **jboss-web.xml**.

Assume a simple scenario *without* the **class-loading** declaration and a fictional **example.jar**:

- If you place **example.jar** in **WEB-INF/lib** *and* it does ***not*** also exist in **jboss//lib**, then **example.jar** will only be visible to that specific WAR.
- If you place **example.jar** in **WEB-INF/lib** *and* it ***does*** also exist in **jboss//lib**, the instance in **WEB-INF/lib** will essentially be ignored and the WAR will use the JBoss server instance's unified class loader to load the **example** classes from **jboss//lib/example.jar**.  (The same would apply to any other WARs or EARs in the same server instance, assuming no **class-loading** overrides.)

The **class-loading** declaration is necessary in cases (such as) where you have two different versions of **example.jar**:
 - jboss//lib:  example1.0.jar
 - WEB-INF/lib: example2.0.jar

In this case, JBoss will create a unique and isolated classloader for your WAR which will avoid **jboss//lib/example1.0.jar** in favour of **WEB-INF/lib/example2.0.jar** in the context of your WAR.

In summary, if you're only running one WAR in the jboss server instance and/or you have no conflicting JAR issues, ditch the **class-loading** declaration and put your JARs in **jboss//lib**. It makes the WAR file more lightweight, overall deployment *may* be simpler and you will not consume additional memory with extra class versions during hot-deploys.

Answer (score 2):

They belong in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your WAR file.  Don't put things in the endorsed folder.